# How to specify a different view path for different route prefix in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

my routes.php

```
Route::controllers([
                   'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
                   'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
               ]);
// Frontend
Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
Route::get('/contact', 'UserController@index');
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/articles', 'ArticleController@all');
Route::get('/article/{id}', 'ArticleController@show')
     ->where('id', '\d+');
Route::get('/messageboard', 'MessageController@messageboard');
// End Of Frontend

// Backend
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::get('/article/create', 'Backend\PostController@create');
    Route::get('/article/edit/{id}', 'Backend\PostController@edit');
    Route::get('/signin', 'Backend\UserController@signin');
    Route::get('/signup', 'Backend\UserController@signup');
    Route::get('/user/{id}', 'Backend\UserController@ucenter');

    Route::post('/article/create', 'Backend\PostController@store');
    Route::post('/article/edit', 'Backend\PostController@update');
    Route::post('/article/del/{id}', 'Backend\PostController@del');
});
```

I put view's file in `resources/views` before I add a new folder `resource/views/backend`; but I have 2 diffenent layouts for both frontend and backend,so I want to organize thme more readable. like below:

```
├── auth
│   ├── login.blade.php
│   ├── password.blade.php
│   ├── register.blade.php
│   └── reset.blade.php
├── backend
│   ├── article_create.blade.php
│   ├── layout.blade.php
│   └── sidebar_menu.blade.php
├── emails
│   └── password.blade.php
├── errors
│   ├── 404.blade.php
│   └── 503.blade.php
├── vendor
├── layout.blade.php
├── article.blade.php
├── articles.blade.php
├── home.blade.php
├── index.blade.php
├── messageboard.blade.php
├── sidebar_menu.blade.php
└── user.blade.php
```

normally I just `@extends('layout')` and it's work fine in frontend

> view files of frontend are placed in default place (`resources/views`)

BUT, I have to `@extends('backend.layout')` to load the layout for backend!

> view files of backend are placed in  `resources/views/backend`

SO, is there any way to make me can load the backend layout template just with `@extends('layout')`?

I saw some piece code refer to 'addNamesapce'...

...poor English ...

*Edit*
Maybe I could use another way to implement my thought. In laravel 5.2 ,blade template can use `@extend('layouts.frontend.app')` to extend frontend template,`@extend('layouts.backend.app')` for backend.

```
resources/views/layouts/frontend/app.blade.php

resources/views/layouts/backend/app.blade.php
```

It's not a big deal.

Comment: I mean keeping the default `resources/views` for frontend , the `resources/views/backend` for backend.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do it the way you want, but you can always edit config/view.php and add this line to the paths array:

```
realpath(base_path('resources/views/backend'))
```

And you'll have direct access to those views. Downside, you can't have 2 views with the same name (you'll have to rename the ones inside backend).

Comment: Thanks , and sorry for my improper Expression. I have clarified my question in the comment : )

Answer (score 0):

Since the view path property on View Finder is protected, you will need to use service container binding for that:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
  $this->app->bind('view.finder', function ($app) {
    $paths = [realpath(base_path('resources/views/admin'))];
    return new \Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder($app['files'], $paths);
  });

  // ...
```